# Does this Interop Instance work for office 365?

Tags: c#, excel, reference, office365

I have this instance

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

 excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
```

and I would like to know if it works for when I have office 365 installed on my computer? or if I have to modify the code line to make it work with office 365

Answer (score 0):

Mirosoft works extremely hard to make sure that every new version of MS Office is fully compatible with previous ones.
The operations above are very simple, therefore there's a 0% chance that they won't work in future versions of MS Office.